# Excel Header Macro maxes out at 3 lines

Tags: vba, excel

This macro is to set a four line left header for all the worksheets in the workbook. The point of this macro is to have control of each line's font size, and attribute i.e bold. I have a separate sheet called header that has the values I use. It will work for 3 lines, but when I add the fourth it bugs out. 
I get this error. 
Run-time error '1004':
Unable to set the LeftHeader property of the PageSetup class

Also note I am running Excel 2010 64 bit.

```
Sub Header()
    '
    ' Header Macro
    '
    lHeader = "&""Calibri,Regular""&10" & Worksheets("Header").Range("B2").Value
    lHeader = lHeader & Chr(13) & "&""Calibri,Regular""&10" & Worksheets("Header").Range("B3").Value
    lHeader = lHeader & Chr(13) & "&""Calibri,Regular""&10" & Worksheets("Header").Range("B4").Value
    lHeader = lHeader & Chr(13) & "&""Calibri,Regular""&10" & Worksheets("Header").Range("B5").Value

    Dim Naam As String, NameFile() As String
    ReDim NameFile(1 To Sheets.Count)

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        i = 1
        For Each shtNext In Sheets
            With Sheets(i).PageSetup
                .LeftHeader = lHeader

                .LeftFooter = Format(Now, "mmmm d, yyyy")

                .CenterFooter = "&""Calibri,Regular""&10" & Format(Worksheets("Header").Range("C8").Value)

                .RightFooter = "&""Calibri,Regular""&10" & Format(Worksheets("Header").Range("D8").Value) & "&p of &N"
            End With
            i = i + 1
        Next shtNext
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: The above code runs just fine for me. I mean it doesn't give any error. Also you might want to set `.ScreenUpdating = True` at the end of the code? BTW, What are the values of `B2:B5` Especially `B5` since adding that line gives you the error... I hope you don't have a formula there which ends in a #error?

Comment: I copied the value of b4 into b5 incase that was the problem. They both just have plain text "July 458 Data". B2="Report 2A", B3="Demographics".

Comment: Runs fine for me in Excel 2010.

Comment: About adding .ScreenUpdating = True. I thought since it is within a with statement that after exiting the with screenupdating goes back to the value it was before the with.

Comment: I have exited out of excel. didn't work. I then restarted computer, and gave it another try. Still got the error.

Comment: Can you upload the file to say wikisend.com and share the link here. Lemme have a look. Also which excel version are you using?

Comment: `About adding .ScreenUpdating = True. I thought sinc....` No you have to set it back :)

Comment: I just successfully ran the macro. I am not sure why, but one of the worksheets was causing the problem. I deleted it and created a new sheet. And pasted/formatted the sheet the same and the macro works now.

Comment: Glad to know it all worked out for you :)

Comment: I was hoping that once it worked for the left header I could apply it to center and right, but Now it is having the same issue those.

Comment: I put a copy of the spreadsheet on wikisend. http://wikisend.com/download/597166/Header.xlsm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 255 character limit is for real, even when separating the macros. The font values are a big part of the total. So I removed them all execpt the last line. But If I ever need a report that has different font sizes. I have a little wiggle room to change 2 of the lines without it getting too big.

```
LHeader = Worksheets("Header").Range("B2").Value
LHeader = LHeader & Chr(10) & Worksheets("Header").Range("B3").Value
LHeader = LHeader & Chr(10) & Worksheets("Header").Range("B4").Value
LHeader = "&""Calibri,Regular""&10" & LHeader & Chr(10) & Worksheets("Header").Range("B5").Value

CHeader = Worksheets("Header").Range("C2").Value
CHeader = CHeader & Chr(10) & Worksheets("Header").Range("C3").Value
CHeader = CHeader & Chr(10) & Worksheets("Header").Range("C4").Value
CHeader = "&""Calibri,Bold""&14" & CHeader & Chr(10) & Worksheets("Header").Range("B5").Value


RHeader = Worksheets("Header").Range("D2").Value
RHeader = RHeader & Chr(10) & Worksheets("Header").Range("D3").Value
RHeader = RHeader & Chr(10) & Worksheets("Header").Range("D4").Value
RHeader = "&""Calibri,Regular""&10" & RHeader & Chr(10) & Worksheets("Header").Range("D5").Value
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that error because you are exceeding the 255 character limit. Unfortunately I couldn't find an MSDN article to back it up but it can be easily re-produced.

The current lengths that you have is

```
HeaderL - 121 
HeaderC - 112
HeaderR - 121

Total   - 354
```

Try this code. Here you can experiment it to reduce the characters.

```
Sub Header()
    HeaderL = "&""Calibri,Regular""&10" & Worksheets("Header").Range("B2").Value
    HeaderL = HeaderL & Chr(10) & "&""Calibri,Regular""&10" & Worksheets("Header").Range("B3").Value
    HeaderL = HeaderL & Chr(10) & "&""Calibri,Regular""&10" & Worksheets("Header").Range("B4").Value
    HeaderL = HeaderL & Chr(10) & "&""Calibri,Regular""&10" & Worksheets("Header").Range("B5").Value

    HeaderC = "&""Calibri,Bold""&14" & Worksheets("Header").Range("C2").Value
    HeaderC = HeaderC & Chr(10) & "&""Calibri,Bold""&14" & Worksheets("Header").Range("C3").Value
    HeaderC = HeaderC & Chr(10) & "&""Calibri,Bold""&14" & Worksheets("Header").Range("C4").Value
    HeaderC = HeaderC & Chr(10) & "&""Calibri,Regular""&14" & Worksheets("Header").Range("B5").Value

    HeaderR = "&""Calibri,Regular""&10" & Worksheets("Header").Range("D2").Value
    HeaderR = HeaderR & Chr(10) & "&""Calibri,Regular""&10" & Worksheets("Header").Range("D3").Value
    HeaderR = HeaderR & Chr(10) & "&""Calibri,Regular""&10" & Worksheets("Header").Range("D4").Value
    HeaderR = HeaderR & Chr(10) & "&""Calibri,Regular""&10" & Worksheets("Header").Range("D5").Value

    If Len(HeaderL) + Len(HeaderC) + Len(HeaderR) > 255 Then
        MsgBox "Oops, You have exceeded the character limit. Please reduce it and try again"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim ws As WorkSheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        With ws.PageSetup
            .LeftHeader = HeaderL

            .CenterHeader = HeaderC

            .RightHeader = HeaderR

            .LeftFooter = Format(Now, "mmmm d, yyyy")

            .CenterFooter = "&""Calibri,Regular""&10" & Format(Worksheets("Header").Range("C8").Value)

            .RightFooter = "&""Calibri,Regular""&10" & Format(Worksheets("Header").Range("D8").Value) & "&p of &N"
        End With
    Next ws

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: @Siddarth_Rout I separated out the macros to be able to run each header by its own. So one for Left, one for Center and one for Right. It appears that If I go into the page layout and edit the headers manually then go back to run the macros it will run one of the macros and the second one will throw an error regardless of the first header macro run. So If I run Rightheader first then run the left header macro. The right will work, but the left doesn't. If I run the left header macro first then the right macro won't work. the len error message you made does not catch this error.

Comment: Even if you separate out the macro, you cannot have more than 255 characters. The total limit whether you use 1 macro or `n` macros will always be 255.